# No sound from music software when using bluetooth headphones

Tags: ubuntu, audio, bluetooth

I linked a [hearphone](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B07C8GM4H1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1) to an Ubuntu 21.04 machine using a [dongle USB 5](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B08B9WQFTL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1). From the figure below, it is clear that the connect has been established, and when I run the test sound, I can clear hear the test so the system communicates with the Bluetooth.

[image]

But, when I play music, for instance from Spotify or Clementine, there is no sound at all. When I use the cable, the music is played perfectly.

What can be the cause of the lack of music?

Thank you

Comment: One possibility I can think of is the application having its own independent settings regarding which device to use for audio output. Those settings may need to be adjusted to use the bluetooth device.

Comment: You were right, Clementine had an option for the output. Now it works. I could not find something similar with Spotify, so that it is still mute, but better than nothing. Thanks!